# Let $f\in C([a,b], X) (X$ is Banach space). Can we say $f$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$  with $a<b,$ and $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function.  We know that continuous  function on a compact set attains maximum and hence $f$ is bounded,  that is,  $|f(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in [a, b]$ and $C$ is some constant.

Now let $X$ be any Banach space, for instance, say $L^{2}(\mathbb R).$  And $f: [a,b]\to X$ is continuous.

> My Question is: Can we say $f:[a,b] \to X$ is bounded?

Comment: You can take $X$ to be any normed space (in order to be able to say what bounded means) and replace $[a,b]$ by any compact topological space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the function
$$[a,b]\to \Bbb R,\quad x\mapsto \|f(x)\|$$
is bounded since $[a,b]$ is compact and the norm function
$$X\to\Bbb R,\quad x\mapsto \|x\|$$
is continuous.